# the first application with spring boot is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to try spring security. I opend the instruction from official web site (https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/). I did step by step first part (prepare application for spring security). Accoring to instruction this application has to work:

1) I made maven dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

2) created first page: src\main\resources\templates\home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
  <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>

  <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

3) created second page: src\main\resources\templates\hello.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

4) created configuration:

```
package hello;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}

}
```

That all. I tried to run this application but I see error-404 for all paths (/, /home, /hello)

Could you explain me what I miss and why my application is not working?

Comment: do you get any exceptions / stacktraces while running the application?

Comment: no the application is working fine. If create file src\main\resources\static\index.html it will be executed when application is started.

Comment: how do you run your application?

Comment: packed my project in war file (through the maven) and deplay this war in tomcat

Comment: are you deploying to the ROOT context?

Comment: I don't undestand the question. I run my application directly through the intellij ( I show it the war file and the tomcat in configuration)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117748/discussion-between-eugene-podoliako-and-funtik).

Answer (score 0):

Check dependencies in your `pom.xml`, try to add spring-context, spring-core, spring-mvc. ALso you can try recreate your project without maven just added spring and other files in your project (sometimes it's work for me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm now sure, but try to add this configuration in the **application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

Answer (score 0):

My class `Application` with `main` method which execute application was located in annother package then my `MvcConfig` class and this was the reason why spring boot cannot find the configuration.